# Не работает функция поиска в односвязном списке в двоичном файле

Tags: c++, файлы, list, консоль

Что нужно исправить?

```
bool findFile(FILE *&f,int Start,int key,int &wp,int &pp)
{
    TNumF *integer;
    wp=Start;
    pp=-1;

    while(wp!=-1)
    {
        fseek(f,wp,SEEK_SET);
        fread(&integer,sizeof(TNumF),1,f);
        if(key==integer->num)
        {
            return true;
        }
         pp=wp;
         wp=integer->next;
    }
     return false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозрительно, что вы читаете указатель из файла:
`fread(&integer,sizeof(TNumF),1,f)`.

Вероятно, вы хотели прочитать структуру TNumF, а не указатель на нее. Тогда:

```
TNumF integer;
...
fread(&integer,sizeof(TNumF),1,f);
if(key==integer.num)
...
```

Comment: верно, что-то не заметил сразу. Спасибо!